# Is there any other way to access safeAreaInsets without using GeometryReader in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I would like to know, is there any other way to access safeAreaInsets without using GeometryReader in SwiftUI? because we can access width and height of screen with this code **UIScreen.main.bounds** I thought may be there is a shortcut to read safeAreaInsets rather than using GeometryReader. thanks for your help and time.

Comment: It is better to formulate what's you try to achieve, because there might other way... or just correct way.

Comment: I need to read safeAreaInsets as much as possible in easy and simple way because using  GeometryReader deform the normal behavior of views and through my old experience it makes Views get heavier than usual to render. because of those 2 points I am trying to find easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it this way, but it doesn't work in the simulator. However, using GeometryReader is the recommended way because it will also update then the device rotates or the view changes.

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.top
```